# python iterative process inside lambda function

Tags: python, loops, lambda

I have a simple python **function**

```
def positiveGauss(mean,stdev):
        result = -1
        while result < 0:
                result = mean + np.random.randn()*stdev
        return result
```

Is it possible to do the same trick using **lambda**? It requires to have iterations inside lambda, but I still believe it is possible.

Comment: AFAIK, no, this is not possible with lambda

Comment: Do you absolutely want to get rid of the `while`? Because there is a statistical way to do this. Has something to do with the inverse normalized function. You pick a (random) real number from the interval [0, _t_] (where 0 < _t_ < 1). Then apply the inverse normalized function to _t_. Do not forget to scale for your parameters `mean` and `stdev`.

Comment: @Elmex80s I need truncated normal distribution. Distribution must be the normal distribution. That is idea from my old statistics text book, maybe not a best one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For diversity's sake:

```
lambda m, s: next(x for x in (m + np.random.randn() * s for _ in iter(int, 1)) if x >= 0)
```

A non-recursive solution that takes advantage of the two-argument form of `iter` and two generator expressions.

`iter(int, 1)` calls `int()` until it returns `1`, which simply can't happen. Therefore the inner generator expression

```
(m + np.random.randn() * s for _ in iter(int, 1))
```

is a generator that evaluates and yields `m + np.random.randn() * s` indefinitely. The outer generator expression takes values from the inner expression one by one, but only yields values that are equal to or greater than zero. The `next` function then takes the first value from the outer generator, which is first value yielded by the inner generator matching the condition.

Comment: it seems it works, but why?! Can you please explain the whole construction better?

Comment: @rth: I added the explanation

Comment: Hm, I like it too. Really don't know which is the better solution, yours or @hashcode55. Both make sense. Thank you.

Comment: @vaultah I'm so gonna use this in golfing! haha

Answer (score 4):

```
positive_gauss = lambda mean, stddev, result = -1: positive_gauss(mean, stddev, mean + np.random.randn()*stddev) if result < 0 else result
```

This is a recursive function. I'll break it down -

```
lambda mean, stddev, result = -1:  # takes 3 parameters 
    positive_gauss(mean, stddev, mean + np.random.randn()*stddev) if result < 0 
    # ^ Your first condition, if its true call the same function modifying result
    else result # if the above one fails just return result.
```

Yes, as @juanpa.arrivillaga this should not be used because its losing the essence of anonymous functions.

Comment: Nice, but you should probably point out that *one would never use this*. In fact, since you've named your lambda, it's not really in the spirit of a lambda function.

Comment: @hashcode55 It is really cool! Thank you! I didn't know lambda can be recursive.

Comment: @rth Yeah indeed they can be. Lambda functions are inspired from functional programming where there is only recursion. No loops.

Comment: after very careful thinking, I decided that @vaultah solution is much better. It isn't overflow stack or memory if mean is negative and we looking for a very small portion of normal distribution.

Comment: @rth yeah, recursion will do face this issue in python (no TCO). I also liked vaultah's solution!