# how to generate increasing sequence of random numbers with given distribution of differences by lambda function

Tags: python, loops, lambda

It is my second attempt to rid of all the function in my python script and use only lambda (s). First attempt was very successful, many thanks to @vaultah and @ hashcode55: [python iterative process inside lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42518960/python-iterative-process-inside-lambda-function), but this one is a bit more complicated. Here the code:

```
from numpy import *

GammaShape, GammaScale = 4, 2.8

def getsequence(tmin,tmax):
    t=[tmin]
    while t[-1] < tmax: 
        t.append( t[-1]+random.gamma(GammaShape, scale=GammaScale) )
    return t

print getsequence(1,100)
```

This function returns increasing sequence of time moments with gamma distributed intervals:

```
[1, 26.428496148321855, 37.98871619324888, 54.30245562952652, 64.30475755683086, 75.76820451443717, 78.62225615406405, 84.16795168540565, 90.64774821744882, 92.51415417744622, 113.42232642308159]
```

Again, I wondering is it possible to realize this function as lambda **without** recursion?

Comment: "It is my second attempt to rid of all the function in my python script and use only lambda (s)" - why would you do that?

Comment: It is a big project that many lambda function are inside a tree, which defined my network model. Classical functions are inside python code, but in my project anything which define network should be 'outside' python code, to be much more flexible. Check my module confpluspy [github.com/rat-h/confpluspy] to see why.

Comment: `lambda` is still Python code and still defines ordinary Python functions. You're not actually gaining any flexibility this way.

Comment: Looking at your github link, I see you're using your own custom parser, which I guess doesn't understand `def`. You're still completely tied to Python, though, and converting `def` to `lambda` only helps your parser understand things. It doesn't actually decouple this file from Python in any way. Why not have your config file just be ordinary Python code?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But in my code network parameters are in something like config file. Script just convert all values in python objects (including lambdas) and puts them into a tree (nested dictionaries). After then script uses them. If one wants to change a behavior it needs just edit one file and not touch a script.

Comment: But you only need to "just edit one file" if that file is Python, too. Your config files are code, the way you have things set up. They're just really weird code with a custom, likely fragile parser. Why not have your config files be regular Python?

Comment: because I also can alter my config by command line parameters, like `myscript.py /some_parameter=value` and value may be also a lambda function. I really want segregate everything which defines my network and scripts which processed it.