# python why lambda behaves differently when it has constant compare to calls random function

Tags: python, lambda

I probably don't understand python's lambda very much. So it confuses me evry time. For example if I have this simple lambda construction with constant, everything works perfect:

```
>>> f = lambda max,x=0:[ x for x in iter(lambda: x+0.5,max+1.) if x<max ]
>>> f(10)
[0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0, 8.5, 9.0, 9.5]
```

But if I substitute  random number generator instead of constant 0.5, it would stuck and never returns back....

```
>>> f = lambda max,x=0:[ x for x in iter(lambda: x+random.random(),max+1.) if x<max ]
>>> f(10)
```

Why?! And what to do to avoid it?

Comment: Because `iter(callable, sentinal)` will only stop if `sentinal` is returned *exactly*. Probably, in this case you *miss* and it keeps going on forever. This is dangerous to do with floating point numbers in general, let alone random ones. This has *nothing* to do with `lambda`, and indeed, you shouldn't be using a lambda function here at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ways to achieve what you want. First, some code-golf:

```
def f(stop): 
    return itertools.takewhile(functools.partial(operator.gt, stop), itertools.accumulate(iter(random.random, object())))
```

I'll leave you to deciphering that as an exercise (a great way to explore itertools!). And also as a good lesson on why you shouldn't write cryptic one-liners...

However, I would probably just do:

```
In [5]: def increase_random(stop, start=0):
    ...:     start += random.random()
    ...:     while start < stop:
    ...:         yield start
    ...:         start += random.random()
    ...:
```

See how much more readable and straight-forward that is? 6 months from now, I'll re-read that and know exactly what I was trying to do.

Here it is in action:

```
In [7]: list(increase_random(5))
Out[7]:
[0.442800767759875,
 1.4148173965715438,
 1.7683959590284435,
 2.116245564487893,
 2.832867264471769,
 3.684055219689638,
 3.986469894067608,
 4.617838198100095]

In [8]: list(increase_random(5))
Out[8]:
[0.5851100455307873,
 1.3248041125729781,
 2.275952338784795,
 2.539203591128045,
 2.7563520512088835,
 3.259124317278677,
 4.1641913798928805,
 4.77771351014472]

In [9]: list(increase_random(10))
Out[9]:
[0.4226041227598847,
 1.0816534967326379,
 1.1540685081566209,
 1.6987578052795809,
 2.118172344169681,
 2.5349681976516156,
 3.137101744986478,
 3.1436528694585766,
 3.455139268185562,
 3.7614777591407975,
 4.072603396579612,
 4.71137983138932,
 5.01309327918888,
 5.098769083492201,
 5.858553103139947,
 5.950601116127209,
 5.956983974085873,
 5.967975512928789,
 6.090114835094137,
 6.105296749316677,
 6.329459825745162,
 6.825175725633318,
 7.738665256248604,
 8.409407710225171,
 9.202163699315623,
 9.497148670699866,
 9.839990622387328,
 9.977297575005993]
```

OK, here is a reward for reading this far... the one-liner works thusly:

`itertools.takewhile` takes a function and an iterable. The `takewhile` will yield from the iterable as long as the function returns `True`. The function I use is `functools.partial(operator.gt, stop)`, which is the partial-application of the `operator.gt`, `op.gt(a, b)` is equivalent to `a > b`, so we take while `stop` is greater than the value returned by the iteterable. Finally, the iterable is `itertools.accumulate(iter(random.random, object())`. `accumulate` (only on Python 3) takes an iterable and keeps adding the iterables values to it... i.e. accumulating. So, e.g:

```
In [10]: list(itertools.accumulate([1, 2, 3, 4]))
Out[10]: [1, 3, 6, 10]
```

The iterable I pass to `accumulate` is `iter(random.random, object())` which just calls random.random until the value is `== object()`, which is *never*.

Comment: No need to wrap `random.random` in a `lambda`.

Comment: And instead of the `partial` you could use `float(stop).__gt__`, though the fact that I had to convert to `float` somewhat shows that `partial` might be the better choice...

Comment: @stefanpochmann Yeah good point about `random.random`. I think the lands wrapper was leftover from  a my earlier attempts. I don't like using dunder methods directly, so I use `operator`

Comment: Thank you!  Good example and nice explanations.

Comment: Naive question, why I need `itertools.takewhile`? Why this won't work  `f= lambda M:[ x for x in itertools.accumulate(iter(random.random, object())) if x<M ]`

Comment: @rth because  `iter(random.random, object())` is an infinite iterator. Just because the condition in the or statement of the comprehension is failing past a certain point doesn't mean the list comprehension will stop iterating over it. And stop wrapping things in `lambda`s like that. if you are going to assign the function to a name, e.g. `f = lambda...` then you should just use a full function definition. In fact, that is part of the official style guide, PEP8.

Comment: @rth think about it this way, if `seq = [2, 2, 3, 4, 3]` , then you wouldn't expect `[x for x in seq if x % 2 == 0]` to result in `[2, 2]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you! But in this case why this answer works? According to you it shouldn't.... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42518960/python-iterative-process-inside-lambda-function]

Comment: BTW in my Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2, i got an error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'accumulate' `.

Comment: @rth Yeah, it's only available on Python 3, but it's easy to implement. Indeed, the [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) have an equivalent Python implementation.

Answer (score 4):

`iter(lambda: x+0.5,max+1.)` stops when the `lambda` function returns **exactly** `max+1.`. The function does return `max+1.`, so the iterator stops there, but that could have gone differently by a fluke of floating-point rounding.

`iter(lambda: x+random.random(),max+1.)` only stops if the `lambda` function returns exactly `max+1.`, but this time, it is extremely unlikely that the function will ever return that value. Your list comprehension filters iterator elements forever.

---

Note that both of your code snippets rely on Python 2 list comprehension variable scope behavior, where the `x` in the comprehension's `for` clause is the same as the `x` from the function the comprehension appears in. That changed in Python 3, so neither of your code snippets work on Python 3.

Comment: Yeah, it's relying on the `x` from the `for` clause is being bound to the free-variable in the `lambda` in `iter`. Had to scratch my head for a bit.

Comment: Thank you, Sorry if it is too unpythonian code. I'm just trying to work around the problem and nothing works. :(

Comment: @rth use `lambda start, step, stop: itertools.takewhile(functools.partial(operator.gt, stop), itertools.count(start, step))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That doesn't have randomness.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I know. You can replace `count` with a function that has randomness. Mostly, I just wanted to play around with `itertools`

Comment: Yep, I need to generate increasing sequence of random time moments with given distribution of intervals. So I don't know how many numbers I'll have at the end

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I challenge you to actually do it :-). I had already tried that and came across a problem I couldn't easily fix.

Comment: @StefanPochmann OK. Here is one with randomness, but I can't get it to *start* somewhere other than 0: `itertools.takewhile(functools.partial(operator.gt, stop), itertools.accumulate(iter(lambda: random.random(), object())))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga could please publish this answer and explain it step-by-step.

Comment: @rth I'm mostly just playing code-golf. I would never use such a monstrosity. I would probably write my own generator, and then use a list-comprehension.

Comment: @rth I'll post an answer

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah, you switched to Python 3. The `accumulate` solves the problem I had.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well the OP is using Python 2 so you switched from that to Python 3.